# Query Eloquent model X and order by property of model Y when X <-> Y are many-to-many

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm having two Eloquent models, one called `Company` and one called `Discounts` and both are releated to each other by a many-to-many relation. *(Meaning one company can have multiple discounts and one discount can be valid for multiple companies.)*

The [Eloquent (Laravel 5.1)](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) based models are defined as following (simplified):

```
class Discount extends Model {
    protected $table = 'discounts';
    public function companies() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company');
    }
}

class Company extends Model {
    protected $table = 'companies';
    public function discounts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Discount');
    }
}
```

Each company also has a `longitude` and a `latitude` column and I am aware of the coordinates of the customer. Finding the nearest companies to the customer would work easily with some trigonometry and `ORDER BY`.

However I want to find all the **discounts of companies near to the customer**. So I need to query `discounts` table, join with the `companies` and order the `discounts` based on the distance of the companies. I would have an idea how to formulate that query with an raw SQL statement, however I don't have any idea how to get that working with Eloquent, which is required since I want to handle the models in my Laravel based PHP web application.

Comment: you can use $discount->companies()->orderBy('columnName')->get();

Comment: well, that would bring me the companies for one discount, however I want to sort all discounts by a property of their company

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution myself:

```
$discounts = $this->discount->select('discounts.*')
            ->leftJoin('company_discount', 'discounts.id', '=', 'company_discount.discount_id')
            ->leftJoin('companies', 'companies.id', '=', 'company_discount.company_id')
            ->orderByRaw("((companies.longitude - $customerLongitude)^2 + (companies.latitude - $customerLatitude)^2) ASC")
            ->get();
```